# sorting and remove duplicate in unix from file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ksh

Below was my input file, but my actual input has millions of records,

```
004,shan@gmail.com,TAT,0582,live,20180622 06:27:47
004,bb@gmail.com,TAT,0588,live,20180622 06:27:27
004,shan@gmail.com,TAT,0562,live,20180622 06:27:59
004,aa@gmail.com,TAT,0582,inlive,20180622 06:27:47
006,dd@gmail.com,TAT,0582,live,20180622 06:27:47
004,tr@gmail.com,TAT,0582,live,20180622 06:27:47
```

Firstly I would Like to sort the above file using Second column(email) ascending order, 
secondly I want to sort it using 6th column (timestamp) in descending order.
Third, I need to remove the duplicate based second column.

Expected Output:

```
004,aa@gmail.com,TAT,0582,inlive,20180622 06:27:47
004,bb@gmail.com,TAT,0588,live,20180622 06:27:27
006,dd@gmail.com,TAT,0582,live,20180622 06:27:47
004,shan@gmail.com,TAT,0562,live,20180622 06:27:59
004,tr@gmail.com,TAT,0582,live,20180622 06:27:47
```

what I tried, but I want to do all in single command instead of different step also the duplicate removal wasn't happening properly with -u?

```
sort -t$'," -k2 pp.txt > pp1.txt
sort -t$'," -k6 -r pp1.txt > pp2.txt
sort -t$'," -k2 -u pp2.txt > pp3.txthere
```

Please help

Answer (score 2):

Using `gnu awk` you can do this in a single command:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"}
!($2 in ts) || $6 > ts[$2] { ts[$2]=$6; row[$2]=$0 }
END { for (i in row) print row[i] }' file
```

```
004,aa@gmail.com,TAT,0582,inlive,20180622 06:27:47
004,bb@gmail.com,TAT,0588,live,20180622 06:27:27
006,dd@gmail.com,TAT,0582,live,20180622 06:27:47
004,shan@gmail.com,TAT,0562,live,20180622 06:27:59
004,tr@gmail.com,TAT,0582,live,20180622 06:27:47
```

Conditions `!($2 in ts) || $6 > ts` has 2 sub-conditions with `OR` clause. 
First condition means if `$2` as key is not present in array named `ts` and 2nd condition means that if `$2` is present then if current timestamp or `$6` is greater than the one present in array (**thus allowing us to store greatest timestamp for same vale of `$2`** in final array)

Comment: could u please explain this !($2 in ts) || $6 > ts [ $2]{ts[$2]=$6; row[$2]=$0 }

Comment: `!($2 in ts) || $6 > ts` has 2 conditions with OR clause. First condition means if `$2` as key is not present in array named `ts` and 2nd condition means that if `$2` is present then if current timestamp is greater than the one present in array (thus allowing us to store greatest timestamp for same vale of `$2`

Comment: could you please tell me, which one would be faster in performance while handling millions of record  using sort command or gnu awk?

Comment: `sort` alone won't give you output as you would pipe it to `awk` or `uniq`. This `gnu awk` is single command so I believe this would be faster and more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You should do it with this:

```
sort -t, -u -k2,2 pp.txt
```

and result is:

```
004,aa@gmail.com,TAT,0582,inlive,20180622 06:27:47
004,bb@gmail.com,TAT,0588,live,20180622 06:27:27
006,dd@gmail.com,TAT,0582,live,20180622 06:27:47
004,shan@gmail.com,TAT,0582,live,20180622 06:27:47
004,tr@gmail.com,TAT,0582,live,20180622 06:27:47
```

Comment: hi thanks for the reply, but Firstly I would Like to sort the above file using Second column(email) ascending order, secondly I want to sort it using 6th column (timestamp) in descending order.. then want to remove the duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
sort -t, -k2,2 -k6,6nr   Input_file | awk -F, '!a[$2]++'
```

Comment: @jcrshankar, please do let me know how your tr result came before shan here? and what you are expecting too please let me know will try to fix it then.

Comment: @jcrshankar, because you haven't copied it correctly `'` you missed it, try complete command and let me know please? I had updated it.

Comment: @jcrshankar, I believe my code is working fine only, please check and confirm once.

Comment: Hi ravi, all working but its not taking the 6th column in descending order.  i want the recent timestamp should present and the old time stamp should get removed in duplicate ..  i want retain 004,shan@gmail.com,TAT,0562,live,20180622 06:27:59

Comment: sort -t, -k2,2 -k6,6  -r   Input_file | awk -F, '!a[$2]++'  I hope this is  right syntax too..

Comment: @jcrshankar, yes syntax is correct, is it working for you?

Answer (score 0):

*GNU* `sort`:

```
sort -t, -k2,2 -k6,6nr -u pp.txt
```

Output:

```
004,aa@gmail.com,TAT,0582,inlive,20180622 06:27:47
004,bb@gmail.com,TAT,0588,live,20180622 06:27:27
006,dd@gmail.com,TAT,0582,live,20180622 06:27:47
004,shan@gmail.com,TAT,0582,live,20180622 06:27:47
004,tr@gmail.com,TAT,0582,live,20180622 06:27:47
```